# Winsorizing, just the outlier or all the value?

Tags: t-test, outliers, winsorizing

I have an outlier in my data set. I want to use the winsorizing quartile (to change the outlier to the 5th% and/or 95th%).

Looking at the quartiles, sometimes I have more values than just my outliers higher than the higher quantile (95). Do I need to change all the values greater than the quartile even if they are not outliers, or do I need to change only the outlier?

Comment: I wonder if this would be better folded into your existing question than as a new question.

Comment: You can ask both. I'm just wondering if it makes more sense to ask them both together or to ask them both separately. I'm not sure, TBH, it's just an idea.

Comment: Don't worry I undestood that, it would make sens but I want to be sure to have answere to all my question.  But it's true date some of the same question can be ask for the winsorizing also